# Implementing sudoku solver in c#

Tags: c#, c++, windows, user-interface, sudoku

I have created a sudoku solver in C++. However I need a GUI for it. Since I am not acquainted with VC++, i cannot creat a GUI with it, going to create it in c#. I have gone through the basics of c# but need a headstart. If i create a windows form application and create a data grid view in the form, how should i go about implementing the functionality in the grid. Below is my C++ code.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>




int a[9][9],b[9][9];

int inputvalue(int x, int y, int value)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if(value == b[x][i] || value == b[i][y])
            return 0;
    }

    for (i = (x / 3) * 3; i <= ((x / 3) * 3) + 2; i++)
        for (int j = (y / 3) * 3; j <= ((y / 3) * 3) + 2; j++)
            if(b[i][j] == value)
                return 0;
    return value;
}

int solve(int x, int y)
{
    int temp;
    if(b[x][y] == 0)
    {
        for(int i = 1;i < 10; i++)
        {
        temp = inputvalue(x, y, i);
        if(temp > 0)
        {
            b[x][y] = temp;
            if (x == 8 && y == 8)
                return 1;
                else if (x == 8)
                {
                if (solve(0, y + 1))
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
            if (solve(x + 1, y))
                    return 1;
            }
        }
         }
         if (i == 10)
         {
             if (b[x][y] != a[x][y])
             b[x][y] = 0;
             return 0;
         }
    }
    if (x == 8 && y == 8)
        return 1;
    else if (x == 8)
    {
        if (solve(0, y + 1))
            return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (solve(x + 1, y))
            return 1;
    }
}



void main()
{
    clrscr();
    for(int i = 0;i < 9;i++)
        for(int j = 0;j < 9;j++)
        {
            gotoxy(i + 1,j + 1);
            cin >> a[i][j];
        }
    for(i = 0;i < 9;i++)
        for(j = 0;j < 9;j++)
            b[i][j] = a[i][j];
    if(solve(0,0))
    {
        for(i = 0;i < 9;i++)
            for(j = 0;j < 9;j++)
            {
            gotoxy(i + 1,j + 1);
            cout << b[i][j];
            }
    }
    else
        cout<<"no solution";
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Way to broad - it is very hard to suggest something concrete to your question... If you need Sudoku solver - there are plenty around. If you need to learn WinForms/WPF - there are plenty samples.

Comment: Have you tried QT or TCL/TK or GTK?

Comment: Try porting the solver code to C# first. Then add a GUI in C#.

Answer (score 1):

well, i guess you'll have a button or something saying the form "start solving"
so, you need to register to the button click:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

and on the `button1_Click` method you need to do your logic, as you showed in your code.
you probably want to know how to address each cell on the `datagridview`. that's easy:

```
dataGridView1[CurrentColumn, CurrentRow]
```

that return a `DataGridViewCell` which you'll convert to your cell (i guess `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`) like so

```
(DataGridViewTextBoxColumn)dataGridView1[CurrentColumn, CurrentRow]
```

or

```
dataGridView1[CurrentColumn, CurrentRow] as DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
```

and then edit that cell using `Text`:

```
(dataGridView1[CurrentColumn, CurrentRow] as DataGridViewTextBoxColumn).Text = MyText
```

Comment: Thanks,got some direction .